# Titanium iPhone : How to access Voice Memos programmatically and store the sound object in a file?

Tags: iphone, titanium, share, voice

I am writing an Titanium iPhone app when I want user to share his Voice Memos records.

There are two options :
(1) Record -> save -> Share
(2) Browse Voice Memo -> Share

I am facing issue in both of this. In (1) I managed to record an audio and play it back. But I am confused how to convert this recorded sound object to file object so that i can share that file. and in (2) I am unable to find out a way to get access to Voice Memos records programmatically.

Any help???

Comment: Do you save your sound file anywhere? If you do then you have to access the file using `Titanium.Filesystem.getFile` and it will work as a file object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to save sound file after a lot of research.
Solution For issue1:

```
var file = var file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile( 'thePath', 'newRecording.wav' );

// Write the data.

file.write( sound.toBlob() );
```

Still working out for second issue. Any help???

Answer (score 0):

don't shure what is Voice Memo, but i can help you with 1st issue:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *err = nil;
    [audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
    if(err){
        NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        return;
    }
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
    err = nil;
    if(err){
        NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        return;
    }

    recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // We can use kAudioFormatAppleIMA4 (4:1 compression) or kAudioFormatLinearPCM for nocompression
    [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];

    // We can use 44100, 32000, 24000, 16000 or 12000 depending on sound quality
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:16000.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];

    // We can use 2(if using additional h/w) or 1 (iPhone only has one microphone)
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];


    // Create a new dated file

    recorderFilePath = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Parking.caf", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER] retain];

    NSLog(@"recorderFilePath: %@",recorderFilePath);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:recorderFilePath];

    err = nil;

    NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[url path] options: 0 error:&err];
    if(audioData)
    {
        NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        [fm removeItemAtPath:[url path] error:&err];
    }

    err = nil;
    recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSetting error:&err];
    if(!recorder){
        NSLog(@"recorder: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        UIAlertView *alert =
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                                   message: [err localizedDescription]
                                  delegate: nil
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        return;
    }

    //prepare to record
    [recorder setDelegate:self];
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;

    BOOL audioHWAvailable = audioSession.inputIsAvailable;
    if (! audioHWAvailable) {
        UIAlertView *cantRecordAlert =
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                                   message: @"Audio input hardware not available"
                                  delegate: nil
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [cantRecordAlert show];
        [cantRecordAlert release]; 
        return;
    }

    // start recording
    [recorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval) 30];
```

Comment: Hey Sentine , thanks for the help. But I am looking forward for the solution for Titanium iPhone application. Do you have any idea about that? And Voice Memo is an in-built application to browse the already recorded audio files.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for issue 1:**

You can create a file object directly and write your recorded data on it like this,

```
// Save the data to file. Overwrite if fill
var file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile( 'Your path', 'yourfile.wav' );

// Write the data.
file.write( recordData );
```

**Solution for issue 2:**
I am not sure if Voice Memos are available in Titanium.

Comment: Thanks for the help..However it didn't worked for me. After lot more research, I managed to save the sound content file using :     file.write( sound.toBlob());

Comment: the variable `recordData` refers tho the sound file :)